# Dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 in Legacy BIOS mode (MBR partition)

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, bios

I need some help with my dual boot. It shows a black screen with `error: invalid EFI file path` when I try to boot Windows from the grub menu. Though the invalid EFI file path is a common problem, I couldn't solve it. I'm currently using Windows 10 Home which is in legacy BIOS mode. All the disks are in MBR partition.

I started to do an online programming course that required me to dual boot Ubuntu, so I tried to install Ubuntu. I have a separate SSD for Windows and Ubuntu, both in MBR partition. After installing Ubuntu I couldn't find Windows in the grub menu. Then I searched online and tried to install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu, but an error occurred and asked me to install manually (dpkg was interrupted).

Then I again booted from the Ubuntu live USB and selected *Try Ubuntu* and then ran Boot-Repair. It worked and now I can see the Windows 10 option in  the grub menu, but then this error comes up - `error: invalid EFI file path`.

Another thing is that Ubuntu SSD went from MBR to GPT partition after installation. My guess is that Ubuntu is now installed in UEFI mode. Is there any way to do the whole thing in Legacy BIOS mode? My BIOS has 2 options related to legacy mode and UEFI.

- Storage Boot Option Control (which is set to Legacy in the below BIOS screen)
- Other PCI devices (which is set to UEFI)

BIOS:

[image]

error: invalid EFI file path:

[image: invalid efi file path picture]

Comment: Unplug your Windows drive. Install Ubuntu on the other drive in the same BIOS/UEFI mode Windows uses, (ie Legacy). Plug in Windows drive. Set Ubuntu drive as the first HDD in BIOS. Boot Ubuntu then in Terminal run `sudo update-grub` , this should add Windows to Ubuntu's boot menu. When booting the Ubuntu drive you will be given a choice to boot Ubuntu or Windows.

Comment: wow, thanks....that actually worked..

Comment: @C.S.Cameron your comment is actually an answer

Comment: @Elder Geek: I have converted it to an Answer, thank you.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Thank You! Most people find answers easier to locate than comments. Already 3 of us liked your answer!

Answer (score 5):

### Dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 in Legacy BIOS mode

- Unplug your Windows drive.
- Install Ubuntu on the other drive in the same BIOS/UEFI mode Windows uses, (ie Legacy).
- Plug in Windows drive.
- Set Ubuntu drive as the first HDD in BIOS.
- Boot Ubuntu then in Terminal run sudo update-grub , this should add Windows to Ubuntu's boot menu.
- When booting the Ubuntu drive you will be given a choice to boot Ubuntu or Windows.

Comment: @HamidKhan If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.

Answer (score 0):

Direct install Ubuntu 22.04 on a hard disk with mbr, doesn't work.  A possible solution, you install at first Ubuntu 20.04 on MBR, it is working. After this you start the upgrade to 22.04, no problem and working without a EFI partition.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just did it, install Xubuntu 22.04. You will have to create a USB install media that boots in MBR mode. I could do that with Rufus on Windows.

On Windows, download the Ubuntu iso that you like and Rufus (https://rufus.ie)

On Rufus, there is an option "Partition scheme". Select MBR. Follow all suggestions of Rufus to create your usb stick.

[image: Partition scheme option on Rufus]

That usb stick is bootable with MBR, the same as your Windows. So you can install dual boot (as I did minutes ago). Success!